# How to verify that a value is a valid date in livecode

Tags: livecode

I am after a code to check the content of a field in livecode and determine if this value is a date or time value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Beyond what Mark implied, the fact that "123456" being a date might break the intent of your handler, and what you already know, that there are several date formats, you may also want to validate the user input at a lower level.

What I mean is that if I were writing a validation routine, I would NOT permit "123456", considering this a data entry error. So you will probably want to test the format of the string itself, making sure it "appears" to be a valid date, as well as actually being a valid date.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use the local date format, you need to set the `useSystemDate` to `true`.

```
set the useSystemDate to true
put "123456" into myDate
put (myDate is a date and myDate is not an integer)
put ("12/12/15" is a date and myDate is not an integer)
```

However, sometimes this may not be what you want. If you provide more specifics, I might be able to come up with a better solution.

Comment: Thanks Mark. I tested your code   using answer field "txtDate" is a date It true for 123456,true for 12/13/15,false for 13/12/15,false for 12/34/56. So code needs to be refine so that it is false for american date and numbers

Comment: 123456 is 11:17:36 AM Fri, 2 Jan 1970 11:17:36 +0100 in seconds. So, it is a date. You could check for integers and set the useSystemDate to true. If you write in your question exactly what you want, I could provide a better answer.